# What is the main reason why the cost function is smoother with L2 regularization?

Tags: regularization

[image: plots of cost function by number of iterations]

[Why does L2 regularization smooth the loss surface?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327909/why-does-l2-regularization-smooth-the-loss-surface) went over my head.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of minimising the MSE as finding an interpolating surface between the $(x_i, y_i)$ pairs. Regularisation is introduced to reduce the contribution of highly noisy single $ y_i $. From that perspective we'd expect the cost surface to become smoother, as we're biasing it be smoother!

Comment: "we're biasing it be smoother"... **how?** I thought we're biasing weights to be smaller. very confused.

Comment: smaller weights lead to a smoother function. How does it lead to a smoother cost function too?

Comment: Could you make your question more specific please?